# converting php to javascript, self-calling functions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, function, plugins

I have this self-calling function in php...

```
function listContent($haystack,$parent) {
    echo '<ul>';

    foreach ($haystack as $f) {
        if($f['parent'] == $parent) {
            echo '<li>';
            echo $f['name'];
            $this->listContent($haystack,$f['fileId']);
            echo '</li>';
        }   
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

which I am trying to write in javascript (jQuery plug) like this

```
    var drawTree = function(self,parent){

        console.log('running...');

        var gd = self.data('galleryData');

        var html = '<ul>';

        for (i = 0; i < gd.length; ++i) {
            if ( (gd[i]['isFolder'] == true) && (gd[i]['parent'] == parent) ) {
                html += '<li data-folder="'+gd[i]['fileId']+'">';
                html += gd[i]['name'];
                self.data(drawTree(self,gd,gd[i]['fileId']));
                html += '</li>';
            }
        }

        html += '</ul>'

        return html
    };

    this.data('drawTree',drawTree); //to make callable outside of plugin initial execution
```

However there seems to be a couple of problems.

First of all, in PHP all calls to the function will be performed before anything is returned.
In javascript however, it seems that the first call to the function is returned first, then the subsequent ones.
So my little trick with the self-call seems pretty much useless.

What would be the preferred way of doing this?

Comment: "PHP all calls to the function will be performed before anything is returned" --- this does not sound right.

Comment: within the loop you need to concatenate the returned html, you don't do anything with the return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved here. The code may have evolved a bit so not exactly the same, but the problem is the same.

[self-calling function inside jQuery plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29561480/self-calling-function-inside-jquery-plugin)