# self-calling function inside jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, nested, self-reference

I am generating a tree (nested UL list) with javascript using the self-calling function below. I might add that it is within a jQuery plugin, if that is at all relevant to the issue (perhaps it might be?).

The variable gd contains a json/array sniffed from a filestructure, so it's basically folders and images's names, and some more data (like the self-explainatory isFolder attribute etc.)

```
        for (i = 0; i < gd.length; ++i) {
```

is interrupted by the self-call.

```
    var drawTree = function(self,parent){

        var gd = self.data('galleryData');

        self.data('sidebar', self.data('sidebar')+'<ul>');

        for (i = 0; i < gd.length; ++i) {

            console.log('looping '+i+': '+gd[i]['name']+', isFolder: '+gd[i]['isFolder']+', parent: '+gd[i]['parent']);

            if ( (gd[i]['isFolder'] == true) && (gd[i]['parent'] == parent) ) {
                console.error(gd[i]['name']);
                self.data('sidebar', self.data('sidebar')+'<li data-folder="'+gd[i]['fileId']+'" class="folderLink">');
                self.data('sidebar', self.data('sidebar')+gd[i]['name']);

                self.data('drawTree')(self,gd[i]['fileId']); // <-- The line causing trouble

                self.data('sidebar', self.data('sidebar')+'</li>');
            }
        }

        self.data('sidebar', self.data('sidebar')+'</ul>');

    };
    this.data('drawTree',drawTree);
```

My problem is that if I leave out the "problem" line

```
self.data('drawTree')(self,gd[i]['fileId']);
```

Which is the one making the self-call (which enables me to also list sub-folders) then I get a neat list of all the "level 0" folders (those without a parent, or parent attribute set to an empty string). But then I will of course not get any of the nested folders.

```
Root
    actions
    appz
    categoriez
    david
    devices
    mimetypes
    places
    space
    status
```

If I do include the self-call, I get all nested levels, but only for the very first of the folders at "level 0", as if the main loop (this line from the code above)

```
Root
    actions
        actionsSub1
            actionSub2
                actionSub3
                    actionSub4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a global variable. Do not treat `var` is as optional.

```
for (i = 0; i < gd.length; ++i) {  <-- i is global
```

now the other function call will not change it when you place var in front of `i`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < gd.length; ++i) {
```

Comment: So simple, yet so important =) Thank you very much.